# How to make libvirtd service to start at boot in Centos 9

Tags: centos, rhel, libvirt, systemctl

I would like to start the service `libvirtd.service` is enabled but do not active at startup

```
[root@GTS ~]# systemctl enable libvirtd.service
[root@GTS ~]# systemctl status libvirtd.service
○ libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor >
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ○ libvirtd-admin.socket
             ○ libvirtd.socket
             ○ libvirtd-ro.socket
             ○ libvirtd-tcp.socket
             ○ libvirtd-tls.socket
       Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
             https://libvirt.org
[root@GTS ~]# systemctl disable libvirtd.service
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/libvirtd.service.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/virtlockd.socket.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/virtlogd.socket.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/libvirtd.socket.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/libvirtd-ro.socket.
[root@GTS ~]# systemctl enable libvirtd.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/libvirtd.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/virtlockd.socket → /usr/lib/systemd/system/virtlockd.socket.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/virtlogd.socket → /usr/lib/systemd/system/virtlogd.socket.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/libvirtd.socket → /usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.socket.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/libvirtd-ro.socket → /usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd-ro.socket.
[root@GTS ~]#
```

I have tried to add my user to the group `libvirt` but is does not work,

Also when I start the `libvirtd.service`

```
[plm@GTS ~]$ systemctl start libvirtd
```

it ask mi password authentication.

Comment: Did you intend to run the `start` as non-root?  That’s why it’s asking for a password…

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enable and start the `libvirtd.socket` unit.  The libvirtd service activates via the socket, which is what you use to connect to the service.

https://libvirt.org/daemons.html#monolithic-systemd-integration

Comment: Thank you. I have read the systems-integration doc which says it is recommended to start on boot the sockets but I miss how to do that in practice. I was testing to uncomment some lines of the configuration file `/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf` but still do not start the service at OS startup.

Comment: Do I have to install `polkit` package?

Comment: It will start when you connect to the socket.

Comment: You probably already have PolicyKit packages installed. If you plan on using PolicyKit for connect to Libvirtd as a non-root user, you will need to make sure you’re in the right groups.

Comment: PolKit is not installed. How. can I connect to the socket at startup?

Comment: @user1993416 maybe you need to tell me why you think the service isn’t starting?  You connect using the UNIx socket and it should auto start.